# Django template variable from text?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have text file with django template variables like:

```
Text {{var1}} text - {{var2}}
```

When I read from file and add to templete:

```
    {% for item in items %}
    {{ item}}
    {% endfor %}
```

have a text on the page:

```
 Text {{var1}} text - {{var2}}
```

In views.py:

```
 c={}
 c['var1'] = '10'
 c['var2'] = '20'
```

How to show variable in template?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Render your file:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('file.txt', {'var1': 'bar', 'var2': 'foo'})
```

Put this rendered string to your template:

```
{{ rendered }}
{% for item in items %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```